# jQuery Dynamic calculation NaN

Tags: jquery

**Hi there,**

I'm having an issue with jQuery, and I don't really understand why. I'm not new to jQuery, but let's say I have much to learn.

The issue is that I have a generated list, which contains a span. `<span class="cost-value">7.040,00</span>`. This is not the only one, there is a whole row of them. Now, what I want is that every value of the span is added to the number, so that I get the total of all these numbers.

For that I wrote the following code.

```
    function countCart(){

    var sum = 0;
    $(".cost-value").each(function() {
        sum =+ Number($(this).html());
    });

    $('.cost-total').html(sum);

}
```

However, when testing it, `sum` does return `NaN`. What am I doing wrong here? I've tried to do it with a data attribute too, with the same result.

**Update:** Okay. I've tried some suggestions. The code is now the following;

```
    function countCart(){

    var sum = 0;
    $(".cost-value").each(function() {
        sum += $(this).data("cost");
    });

    console.log(sum);
    $('.cost-total').html(sum);

}
```

However, this will add every number to the string in sum. I Want all numbers to add on eachother, so that I get one number.

Comment: Your span doesn't have a data-cost attribute. Add data-cost ='7.040,00' to your span and then try again.

Comment: Or use `sum += Number($("this).text())`

Comment: Use `.text()` rather than `.html()` - but in this case should be the same.  Looks like you have `=+`  rather than `+=`

Comment: @freedomn-m I Tried using `.text()`, but it returns the same. I'm using `=+` because I want numbers to add to eachother, not to add to the string. Example `10 + 2 = 12`

Comment: The issue is with `Number()` and the value you're checking:  `7.040,00` is not a valid "number" as it has a comma in the decimal part.  Remove the comma (`7.04000`) and it works fine.  Though =+ will mean you only get the last value... https://jsfiddle.net/jmpn0Lsu/

Comment: @freedomn-m Okay, the two zeroes I can add later. However, I want the final result, every number added on eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` instead of using the "class" `Number`.

`Number` expects a number value while `html`, `text`, `attr` or `data` functions returns a string.

So your code will look like this:

```
function countCart(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".cost-value").each(function() {
        sum =+ parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $('.cost-total').html(sum);
}
```

EDIT: You are using a localized string, so `parseFloat` should not work. Your best "bet" is to put the "raw" value in a `data` attribute and retreive the value with `data`function (without omitting to use `parseFloat`).

Here is the code for my suggestion:

```js
function countCart(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".cost-value").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).data("cost"));
    });
    $('.cost-total').html(sum.toLocaleString("de-DE", {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
}

countCart();
```

```css
.cost-total {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost-value" data-cost="7040.00">7.040,00</span>
<span class="cost-value" data-cost="3040.00">3.040,00</span>
<span class="cost-value" data-cost="2040.00">2.040,00</span>
<span class="cost-value" data-cost="1040.00">1.040,00</span>
<span class="cost-total"></span>
```

Comment: `Number("123")` works fine, so passing a string is not an issue.  Agree with `parseFloat` though .

Comment: But the string is localized. Look at the thousands seprator and the decimal one.

Comment: Indeed - and that's why `Number` is failing (7.040,00 is not recognised as a number) - *however* parseFloat *also* has the same issue and just ignores the bits it doesn't like - so localised 7.040,00 (I assume means 7 thousand and 40) is parseFloat'd as 7.04 (7 point zero 4).

Comment: I was referring to your assertion that Number "expects a number...[implied not] a string"

Comment: See the snippet I made based on my suggestion of using `data` attributes.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I'm trying your code, however, it will remove the last zeroes and will use a comma, For example: I Have the number `171.360`. The total result will be `171,36`. This is a whole lot less as what I want. It hops from `Thousands + Hundreds + Cents` to `Hundreds + Cents`

Comment: Look carefully to the snippet, the sum is based on the `data` atrribute and then converted to the good locale. Run the snippet and see: the result is correct.

Comment: I See. I just found an issue I Created myself. After solving that one, this one worked. Thanks.